# How to add a company logo to paypals SDK V2

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'am trying to add a company-logo by using the PayPal SDK environment in PHP.

I have seen that this is possible, but there is no documentation.

I tried the following without success:

```
        'application_context' =>
        [
            'return_url'           => "https://example.com/return",
            'cancel_url'           => "https://example.com/cancel",
            'image_url'            => "https://xyz.de/test/paypal_logo.jpg",     
            'logo_image' and LOGOIMG do not works also       
        ],
```

Thanks for any hint in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on the products you use, but generally you can create a [Payment Experience Web Profile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#web-profiles_create). See a [sample here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payment-experience/CreateWebProfile.php). After creating it, you will get a *Profile ID*.

When you initialize your payment, you can pass the *Profile ID* with the method `setExperienceProfileId`

Comment: THX Andrea. Isn't it V1?